# How to speed up creating regular grid in chunks and Writing to file is slow

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation, python-multiprocessing, gdal

I am trying to interpolate scattered points to a regular grid.
For small domains i.e., small number of rows and cols `np.meshgrid` works fine. 
If the rows and cols are large, It throws `MemoryError`.
So I tried processing entire domain in smaller chunks and apply the interpolation function and writing it to geotiff file using gdal.
Below is the code and I have given explanation in comments.

```
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal
import csv
import scipy.spatial as spatial

## loading lat, lon and values from csv file
lat = []
lon = []
ele = []

## The csv file contains the lat/lon/ele 
with open('data.csv', 'r') as data:
    for row in data:
        row = row.strip().split()
        lat.append(float(row[2]))
        lon.append(float(row[1]))
        ele.append(float(row[3]))
## creating a numpy array to feed into KDTree for spatial indexing      
xycoord = np.c_[lon,lat]
ele_arr = np.array(ele)

## Generating KDTree for nearest neighour search
point_tree = spatial.cKDTree(xycoord, leafsize=15)

## Getting domain extents
## 23.204 , 146.447, -61.509, 25.073
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = min(lon),max(lon), min(lat), max(lat)  

res = 0.003 ## Grid spacing ~~330 meters 

x = np.arange(xmin, xmax, res, dtype=np.float16)
y = np.arange(ymin, ymax, res, dtype=np.float16)

nx = x.shape[0]
ny = y.shape[0]
print (nx, ny) # ~ (41081 28861)

## Creating of geotiff file using gdal
outFile = "test.tif"
format_ = "GTiff"
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(format_)
outRas = driver.Create(outFile, nx, ny, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32, options=['COMPRESS=DEFLATE'])
outRas.SetGeoTransform((xmin, res, 0, ymax, 0, -res))

## No of rows and columns in each chunk
step = 2000 

## starting and ending indices for row and column for each chunk
xstart = []
xend = []
ystart = []
yend = []

for i in range(0,nx,step):
    for j in range(0,ny,step):
        xstart.append(i)
        xend.append(i+step)
        ystart.append(j)
        yend.append(j+step)

## Actual loop      
for i in range(len(xstart)):
    t = np.meshgrid(x[xstart[i]:xend[i]],y[ystart[i]:yend[i]]) ## Creating a meshgrid 
    ## Actual intended flow
    ## xy = np.stack(np.meshgrid(x[xstart[i]:xend[i]],y[ystart[i]:yend[i]]), axis = -1)
    ## distances, points_idx = point_tree.query(xy, k=3, eps=0)
    ## z = interpFn(distances, ele_arr[points_idx])

    ##To test the speed, not using above code and using a simple fn which 
    ##takes our input matrix and return matrix with same dimensions. even np.ones() will do

    z = fn(t) ## this could be any function
    outRas.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(z,xstart[i],ystart[i]) ## Writing to geotiff file 

outRas = None
```

Now the `MemoryError` is resolved, but for large size matrices it is very slow and takes lot of time just to write a simple matrix even before any function is applied.Kindly provide suggestions to speedup the the process

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your initial issue (depending on the content of your data) setting the `sparce` parameter to `True` could potentially save you a lot of memory:

```
np.meshgrid(data, data, sparse=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. In my code, the `meshgrid` is stacked and is used in the `cKDTree.query`. While using sparse I can't do `np.stack` and even if I could, the `query` will be very slow for large data. So, I am actually looking to modify this using python `multprocessing` or some way of parallelizing this method